# Is it possible to construct an enclosure with zero ionizing radiation inside?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

Is it possible to construct an enclosure/shield where the Geiger counter would not detect any rays?

Or put in another way, is there a location (man-made or natural) on earth where a very sensitive geiger counter would not detect any ionizing radiation?

I'm trying to look up such experiments, but failing so far

Comment: I see there is a close vote for this as an "engineering" question.   In my opinion, this should still be on topic here.  It seems to be asking if it is possible in theory to construct such a device; which to me is still a good conceptual physics question.

Comment: That partly depends on how sensitive your Geiger counter is. Many experiments go to great length (using steel from sunken WW1 ships, using old mines, ...) to avoid as much background as possible.

Comment: Over what length of time are you watching the Geiger counter? Also, what is the false positive rate (the "fake hit rate", if you will) of the Geiger counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or put in another way, is there a location (man-made or natural) on earth where a very sensitive Geiger counter would not detect any ionizing radiation?

No. Ionizing radiation, from cosmic rays as well as radioactive elements in the Earth's crust, is impossible to fully shield against.

However, you can do a heck of a lot in creating really effective shielding that will protect you from the vast majority of this radiation, and there are plenty of sensitive nuclear- and particle-physics experiments that require these environments and are therefore placed in those locales, which are typically in old mines and deep underground.

Some examples, in no particular order:

- [Gran Sasso National Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laboratori_Nazionali_del_Gran_Sasso)
- [Super-Kamiokande](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Kamiokande)
- [Sanford Underground Research Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanford_Underground_Research_Facility)
- [China Jinping Underground Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Jinping_Underground_Laboratory)
- [ANTARES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTARES_(telescope))
- [Baksan Neutrino Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baksan_Neutrino_Observatory)

There's more, but you get the point.

Comment: there is no where on Earth where you can hide from solar neutrinos, and shielding is what converts them into charged particles.

Comment: @JEB There's also an uninteresting semantics debate to be had (or not) about whether neutrinos are ionizing radiation. But yes.

Comment: I would say "no", they are categorically not (except near the core of a supernovae). But they occasionally turn into charged leptons which are, and would spoil the OP's "zero" requirement.